# binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8"); and Unix line endings in Strawberry perl

Tags: perl, newline

With Strawberry perl v5.28.1 on Windows 10 I am trying to achieve the same result as on Linux - namely get a UTF8 encoded file **with Unix line endings**.

Here is my Perl script:

```
#!perl -w

use strict;
use utf8;
use Encode qw(encode_utf8);
use Digest::MD5 qw(md5_hex);

binmode(STDIN, ":utf8");
binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");

my %words;

while(<>) {
        # change yo to ye
        tr/ёЁ/еЕ/;

        # extract russian word and its optional explanation
        next unless /^([А-Я]{2,})\|?([А-Я ,-]*)/i;
        my ($word, $expl) = (uc $1, $2);

        if (length($word) <= 3) {
                print $word;
                # if explanation is missing, omit the pipe
                print (length($expl) > 3 ? "|$expl\x0A" : "\x0A");
        } else {
                # print the md5 hash and omit the pipe and explanation
                print md5_hex(encode_utf8('my secret' . $word)) . "\x0A";
        }
}
```

Here is my input file:

```
ААК|Плоскодонное речное судно
ААРОНОВЕЦ|
ААРОНОВЩИНА|
ААТ|Драгоценный красный камень в Японии
АБА|Толстое и редкое белое сукно
АБАЖУР|
АБАЖУРОДЕРЖАТЕЛЬ|
АБАЗ|Грузинская серебряная монета
АБАЗА|
```

Here is how I run it (I use `type` instead of `<` because I have numerous input files in my real use case):

```
type input.txt | perl encode-words-ru.pl > output.txt
```

Regardless of what I try in the above Perl source code, the lines in output.txt are terminated by \x0D\x0A

Please help me to stop perl from "helping" me!

Comment: From [perlio documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/PerlIO.html): *If you want UNIX line endings on a platform that normally does CRLF translation, but still want UTF-8 or encoding defaults, the appropriate thing to do is to add :perlio to the PERLIO environment variable.* Probably worth investigating that approach.

Comment: You should also be using `:encoding(UTF-8)`, not `:utf8`, btw

Comment: Unfortunately, your both suggestions have not helped: `@SET PERLIO='perlio'` and `binmode(STDOUT, ":encoding(UTF-8)");`

Comment: It says to use `:perlio` not `perlio`. Colons are important. (I don't have access to a Windows computer at the moment for my own testing).

Comment: And the documentation I linked explains why `:encoding(UTF-8)` is preferable (though most of the examples don't use it, sigh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a better way, but you could make `STDOUT` a `:raw` file handle and then encode the output there yourself.

```
binmode STDOUT;    # or  binmode STDOUT, ":raw";
...
print (length($expl) > 3 ? encode_utf8("|$expl\n") : "\n");   # $exp1 is already decoded
...
print md5_hex(encode_utf8('my secret' . $word)) . "\n";
```